# slideToggle function to slide down the selected div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i need help about this JQuery code again i really have a little experience with JQuery so sorry if the question is a mess..
ill credit http://www.w3schools.com for this one since i copied it from them

```
//the JS code
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

<p class="flip">click to view full credit report details</p>
<div class='panel'>                              
 <?php                          
   display_column_name($table_name,$table_id);
 ?>
</div>
```

ok so the code is actually looped it repeats depending on how many data i have in my database so the problem right now is when i click on "Click to view full credit report details" it opens everything.. what i want is when i click on that it only opens that portion... and not the others... any idea about this? i really need help thanks :)

Comment: You have to use ids or indexes for this kind of operation. You are using class names and all divs have same class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have dynamic id for each p element. which calls div with another dynamically setted id.

in your loop you could do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#flip_<?php echo $id_from_database;?>").click(function(){
    $("#panel_<?php echo $id_from_database;?>").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

and your html, this should be within loop as well

```
<p id="flip_<?php echo $id_from_database;?>">click to view full credit report details</p>
<div id='panel_<?php echo $id_from_database;?>'>                              
 <?php                          
   display_column_name($table_name,$table_id);
 ?>
</div>
```

**OR**

**Second method**

tHIS CODE INSIDE LOOP

```
<p id="flip_<?php echo $id_from_database;?>" onclick="expandDiv('<?php echo $id_from_database;?>')">click to view full credit report details</p>
    <div id='panel_<?php echo $id_from_database;?>'>                              
     <?php                          
       display_column_name($table_name,$table_id);
     ?>
    </div>
```

javascript function outside loop

```
function expandDiv(id){
   $("#panel_"+id).slideToggle("slow");
}
```

Where

`$id_from_database` is the unique id of the records that come from database.

Comment: yeah the code above is in the loop.. except for the JS.. so i need to loop the JS too right?

Comment: @LouieJayJayme Please check my edit. If you use first method js should be within loop. But if you use second method javascript should be out of the loop.

Comment: LoVeSmItH it worked :) the first one uhm ill just deal with this first one.. i think ill need to make more specific name in the ID.. it closes back when i try to open it maybe because they have the same id name anyway thank you very much :)

Comment: @LouieJayJayme, ID SHOULD BE UNIQUE FOR EACH ROW, LIKE THE RECORD ID THAT COMES FROM DATABASE LIKE `flip_1, flip_2,..., flip_45` and so on

Comment: yeah yeah i just tried.. well the stuff i'm doing seems to have something like a category so i have to test that too so right now im having names like "panel_account_1" thanks to you :)

Comment: LoVeSmItH can i ask one more question? uhm the table stuff seems to display even if it's under that div.. what must i do with it? i tried it on CSS no effect :(

Comment: @LouieJayJayme, try to increase `z-index` to something bigger like `99` for the div in your css.

Comment: i think the z-index doesn't have something to do.. it doesn't display right on the #panel but displays outside.. i tried to recreate the scenario on w3school's try it.. and it works fine in there

Comment: @LouieJayJayme. Sorry I misunderstood your problem. It would have been better and much easier for me to understand your problem if I can see your code LIVE.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.report a').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('.detail').slideUp('slow');
        $('#detail_'+id).slideDown('slow');
    });
});
</script>

<style>
    .detail{display: none;}    
</style>
<div id="reports">

    <div class="report">
        <a id="1" href="#">click to view full credit report details</a>
        <div class="detail" id="detail_1">
            Here are details related to report # 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="report">
        <a id="2" href="#">click to view full credit report details</a>
        <div class="detail" id="detail_2">
            Here are details related to report # 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="report">
        <a id="3" href="#">click to view full credit report details</a>
        <div class="detail" id="detail_3">
            Here are details related to report # 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Loop:**
Inside your loop you have to make dynamic ids like this

```
<div class="report">
    <a id="<?php echo $current_record_id; ?>" href="#">click to view full credit report details</a>
    <div class="detail" id="detail_<?php echo $current_record_id; ?>">
        <?php echo $detail; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the code Tahir Yasin.. but i got things working now :) thanks though :)

Comment: @tahir, line `$('#detail_'+id).slideDown('slow');` should be `$('#'+id).slideDown('slow');`

Comment: No, it will slideDown link itself not its hidden details, to slideDown hidden details, you have to slide down the detail_+id , hope you got my point.